# DOJO How to remove Menu border

Tags: dojo

```
ready(function(){
                var onItemSelect = function(evt){
                    var item = registry.getEnclosingWidget(evt.target);

                var menu = new Menu({
                }, "profileCompletenessMenu");

                menu.addChild( new MenuItem({
                    id: "11",
                    label: "Photo",
                    style:"height:20px"
                }) );               
                menu.addChild( new MenuItem({
                    id: "12",
                    label: "Profile",
                    style:"height:20pxs;"
                }) );
```

Above code create Menu. I am trying to remove menu border please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example, I was using the claro theme, so I override the css using the following:

```
.claro .dijitMenu {
    border: none;    
}
```

You can see the example here http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/2PLDX/